# Defining the one to many relationship in OnModelCreating using Entity Framework Core 3.1

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am new to Entity Framework Core 3.1 and trying to define the one-to-many relationship between two tables. I am currently struggling and getting compilation errors. Could somebody tell me what the problem could be.

The error is:

> PersonNote does not contain the definition for PersonNote

I am currently getting is at line

```
entity.HasOne(d => d.PersonNote)
```

How else could I define one-to-many relationship?

The two tables are `Person` and `PersonNote`. One `Person` can have many `PersonNote`s. I have defined the models for them

```
public class Person
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? TitleId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string FirstNamePref { get; set; }
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int? PartnerId { get; set; }
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public Title Title { get; set; }
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        internal static IEnumerable<object> Include(Func<object, object> p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public PersonNote PersonNote { get; set; }
}

public class PersonNote
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string Note { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordStartDateTime { get; set; }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
        public DateTime RecordEndDateTime { get; set; }
}



public IEnumerable<PersonNote> GetPersonNotes(int personId)
        {
             var PersonNotes = PersonNote
               .Include(x => x.)
                  .Where(x => x.Id == personId)
               .ToList();

            return PersonNotes;
        }
```

I have tried the following in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PersonNote>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("PersonNote", "common");
                entity.HasOne(d => d.PersonNote)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Person)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.PersonId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_commonPersonNote_commonPerson");
            });
```

Comment: Your entity is `PersonNote` (`Entity<PersonNote>`) - it doesn't have `PersonNote` property. There should be `Person` navigation property.

Comment: I added but the error that i mentioned above is still there

Comment: public Person Person { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have have something like this (other properties are omitted):

```
class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<PersonNote> PersonNotes { get; set; }
}

class PersonNote
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
}

class StackOverflow : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PersonNote> PersonNotes  { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.PersonNotes)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.PersonId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Johny the error seems to have gone but my method GetPersonNotes needs to return personnotes for specific personid. I am not able to add the Person entity in the includes. I tried adding the following in personnote  public Person person { get; set; }

        internal static IEnumerable<object> Include(Func<object, object> p)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

Comment: But that doesnt seem to work. The whole idea of establishing the relationship is to be able to return the results from that query

Comment: @Tom If you need notes for specific persons, then filter by these persons and include their notes. For instance: `context.Persons.Where(p => p.Id == 10).Include(p => p.PersonNotes);`

Comment: I am actually looking at querying the personnotes table by person and not the other way round.

Comment: @Tom `var ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; context.PersonNotes.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.Id));` It will generate `IN (1,2,3)` T-SQL.

Comment: @Tom That `Include` method in Person doesn't belong there. `Include` is a built-in Entity Framework method. But you're expanding on your original question now. That doesn't work well and should be avoided. Your question was answered. If you have new questions, please start a new question.

Comment: @Jonny what you are suggesting is this  var PersonNotes1 = PersonNotes.Where(p => Person.Contains(p.Id));    but I am getting error Person does not contain a definition for Contains

Comment: @GertArnold its related as my query wont work if the models arent correctly defined. I am ensuring if the models are correct and we arent missing anything

Comment: Which query? You only brought up this `GetPersonNotes` method after you got the answer. Anyway, I'm sure JohnyL will be able to show how things change if `PersonNote` has a navigation property `Person`.

Comment: @Tom You want to get data from `PersonNotes` tables containing Persons' IDs. My `var ids = ...` array holds these IDs which are used to get data from `PersonNotes`. So, you must have a list of these IDs (IEnumerable). Did you import `System.Linq`?

Comment: Beg your pardon, but I agree with @GertArnold - I have answered your question. If you have another question - start a new one.

Comment: Hi Jonny my method will get only one id at a time and i need to traverse the Personnotes table based on that id. I dont have multiple ids. The id i am passing to the method is personid. One personid can contain many notes

Comment: @Tom I have invited you to chat - let's discuss there! 